# Gravity Forms Authorize.Net add-on - Set a Start Date for Recurring Transaction

Tags: php, html, wordpress, authorize.net, gravity-forms-plugin

Is there any way, preferably without editing core code, to set the "Start Date" parameter when sending an ARB recurring transaction request to Authorize.Net using the Gravity Forms plugin with the Authorize.Net add-on?

Looking in the plugin code, it looks like there used to be some sort of way to do this

```
//line 929 of /plugins/gravityformsauthorizenet/authorizenet.php    
$subscription = apply_filters("gform_authorizenet_before_start_subscription", $subscription, $form_data, $config, $form);
```

Answer (score 0):

In /wp-content/plugins/gravityformsauthorizenet/authorizenet.php on line 462 there is a filter being applied to the subscription variable created on the line above it (460). If you look at the contents of the get_subscription() method in that same file (line 228) you'll see all of the available settings that you can change programmatically.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_authorizenet_subscription_pre_create', 'change_subscription_config', 10, 1 );
function change_subscription_config( $subscription ) {

    $subscription->startDate = gmdate( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "insert your date here" ) );
    return $subscription;

}
```